# Check if date between range if not move to next

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have data that has a ID im matching on but multiple rows of dates and I need to search for the ID then check if the date is equal to or between two dates and if so return invoice number if not keep going through the data.

The formula below works but only tests if in range on the first found, as im using vlookup but im unsure what formula I need to be using to do this. If it is out of range I need to keep looking until the end of data.

```
=IF(AND(Startdate>=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!H2,Data!K:R,8,0),Sheet1!Enddate<=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!H2,Data!K:R,8,0)),"Potiential Match","out of range")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
=IF(MMULT((K2:R17>=Startdate)*(K2:R17<=Enddate),--((A1:A8)*0=0))*MMULT(--(SHEET1!H2=K2:R17),--((A1:A8)*0=0))=1,R2:R17,"")
```

Change the "17"'s to be the bottom of your data you want to search through.